# What do we call this pocket of fabric in which we put tent poles when assembling a camping tent?

Tags: word-request, translation

When assembling a camping tent, we sometimes have to put the tent poles through a kind of tunnel created using a strip of the same fabric of which the tent is made.

The Russian term for this channel (tunnel? pocket?) is **kuliska** (кулиска). I wonder what the English term is for this.

[image]

On the image, you can see a tent pole that creates the camping tent's frame (каркас). This tent pole emerges from a "kuliska" and then dives into another "kuliska".

Multitran [offers several translations](http://www.multitran.ru/c/M.exe?l1=2&l2=1&s=%EA%F3%EB%E8%F1%EA%E0) but I'm not sure they fit.

The same word is used in Russian for the channel in which we put a decorative band or a belt or string to support a piece of clothing:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends.  If the "pocket" is closed at one end (for the end of the pole to fit into) then **pocket** or **slot** might be fine.  If the fabric instead forms a *tube* that the pole is meant to slide *through* then we could call it a **sleeve**.

> To set up the tent, slide the poles through the **sleeves** along the end of the tent, and set the ends of this frame firmly into the ground.

I don't think there is any special name for the "channel" through which we would run a piece of fabric or string (like that used to hold up a pair of sweatpants) but the string itself is called a **drawstring**.

Also, if the fabric through which the pole would go is very narrow, we would call it a **loop** rather than a sleeve, as in a ["belt loop"](http://www.heddels.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/12.beltloops-stitched-under-waistband.jpg) for pants.

Comment: For the record - a drawstring runs through a _casing_.